# calulating PPI with 10.1 inch (diagonal)

Tags: ppi

Frequently devices are described in diagonal screen measurements.

How do I calculate the PPi (pixels per inch) for a device that is 10.1 inch (diagonal) and 1920x1200 pixels.

Comment: Using [mathematics](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a online calculator like any one of these [google searches](https://www.google.com/search?q=dpi+from+diaginal+calculation&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)